# How do I pass custom metadata from setup.py to my application code

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm writing a setup.py file for my python package and have information in a dictionary that I want to pass to the setup command that will then be accessible to the application code when the package is installed.

Is there a standard way to pass information like this in the setup function without writing and then including files (data / package) or writing a manifest file?

Comment: No, I do not think what you can do is possible, or maybe there is a way but I would probably recommend against it. What is important to know is that `setup.py` does not necessarily run at installation time. It runs at build time, either when building a sdist or a wheel, but not at install time. Installations are typically made exclusively from a wheel and the wheel does not contain the `setup.py` script.

Comment: I'd put that data in the external file and have it used by both setup and your app. that way you do not need to pass anything

Comment: Thanks! Yes my setup.py runs to build a wheel, and I want to include things like who built the wheel, on what machine, and other data that's available when setup.py is run to build the wheel. Then later when someone installs the package, this data needs to be available to the application code (setup.py is no longer available).

Comment: Okay thanks -- I was hoping to avoid an additional data file but perhaps there's no way around it.

Comment: Yes if I were you I would let my `setup.py` script write my custom data in some file (could be a `.py`, or JSON, or whatever) then I would make sure that this file is packaged correctly into the distribution artifacts (sdist and/or wheel).

Comment: Maybe this discussion is helpful: https://discuss.python.org/t/add-custom-metadata-to-wheel-file/21410

Comment: I think it is the `build_py` command of `setup.py` that you should override: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/extension.html